# What cage is this

Tags: shimano, derailleur-rear

I have this rear XTR Shadow+ derailleur and I wanted to know if it's compatible with [OneUp RAD Cage](http://www.oneupcomponents.com/products/r-a-d-cage) (which is for Shimano medium cage) :

[image]

Will it work ?

Comment: I would call that a long cage.  Its a shame the rad cage doesn't have measurements posted on its website to help prospective buyers.

Comment: Well, its designed for one family of parts, so its unnecessaryy. Its like saying "This air filter is for 2004-2008 Honda Civics". You could put the measurements, but anyone whose going to buy it is going to check just based on the model year of their civic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few simple ways to determine this:

1. Take a ruler and measure the cage length. Then compare it with the Shimano spec sheet for the model of the derailleur.
2. Look to see if SS/GS/SGS is written somewhere on the derailleur. SS means short cage, GS means medium cage. SGS means long cage.
3. See what the cog sizes are and calculate the required capacity. If its sufficiently high, it may imply its SGS.

Comment: I used the 1. , it's a long cage